# how to make a hole in a layer of stack or how to replicate the shown deisgn

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Actually i am trying to make the following UI but i am not able to achieve that sort of hole or transparent layer below the yellow button. Have tried glassmorphism plugin and backgrop filters to acheive the glass frost efftet. Just would like to know how to make that hole.

Desired UI:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use clipRRect or clipRect to make this design. these two widgets will help you cut/clip the container in the required shape.

For more information, you can have reference from [here](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/cliprrect-clippath-in-flutter-4c41abe4e8).